# How to use createPersistedState in a vuex and quasar application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How to use createPersistedState in a vuex and quasar application?

I am trying to persist some daos in the cookie of my application, however the data is not being written in the cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your attention of all.

Action

```js
function setUser ({ commit }) {
  axios.get(`/modulo/app`, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + store.getters.getToken() } })
    .then(response => {
      commit('setUserMutation', response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (!error.response) {
        console.log(error.response)
      }
    })
}
```

Mutation

```js
const setUserMutation = (state, data) => { state.user = data }
```

Getters

```js
function getUser (state) {
  return state.user
}
```

index config Store

```js
export default function () {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      auth
    },
    plugins: [createPersistedState(
      {
        paths: ['auth.setUserMutation'],
        storage: {
          getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
          setItem: (key, value) => Cookies.set(key, value, { expires: 3, secure: true }),
          removeItem: key => Cookies.remove(key)
        }
      }
    )],
    strict: process.env.DEV
  })
  return Store
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely it's due to the secure props you use in Cookie.set

> secure
>
> Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
>
> -https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

If you are developing on `localhost`, it most likely is not using HTTPS.

You can set the secure value to be based on your environment, by using env variable

```
secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
```